# The code below keeps returning undefined when summing through a looping array

Tags: javascript

The code below returns undefined for the sum of the array, any help?

```
    var myExpenses = [];
            var total;

        function appendExpenses() {
            var expense = document.getElementById('cost').value;
            myExpenses.push(expense);
            console.log(myExpenses);

            function totalExpense() {
                for (var i = 0; i < myExpenses.length; i++) {
                    total = total + myExpenses[i];
                }
                return total;
            }
            console.log(total);
        }
```

Comment: Your code never calls the `totalExpense()` function. Also `total` should be initialized to 0.

Comment: I agree with @Pointy

Comment: @AlexGoonerArteta You might want to either delete your question then, or [post an answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the working code (thanking the comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Always try to give a meaningful default value for variables.

   var total = 0;
2. Always try to convert data type explicitly.

   var expense = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cost').value)
3. Always try to check the data

   if (!isNaN(expense)) myExpenses.push(expense)
4. Don't forget to call your function.

   ```
   function appendExpenses() {
       const myExpenses = [];
       let total = 0;
       let expense = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cost').value);
       if (!isNaN(expense)) {
         myExpenses.push(expense);
       }

       console.log(myExpenses);
       // unnecessarilly closure, but since we are learing...
       return function () {  // or use reduce, but since we are learning...
           for (var i = 0; i < myExpenses.length; i++) {
               total += myExpenses[i];
           }
           return total;
       }
   }

   const totalExpense = appendExpenses()
   console.log(totalExpense())
   ```